# What do I need to learn to create an online, project-management database?

Tags: programming-languages

A friend of mine owns a repair shop. He takes in broken electronics and fixes them. In talking to him, he mentioned that he wished he had some online-based (or at least network-based, so he could access it from any computer in his shop) way to track/log his customers and their information, products, histories, charges, and the current status of items. 
For example, someone brings in a toaster oven that doesn't work. He goes to the computer, adds them to the database if they're not already in there (lookup by email, name, phone, or address), then adds their toaster oven (item name, model number, problems, repairs, cost). He can do this with each item and each person, and a list of current products requiring action is generated. Then as he completes repairs, he checks them off as "repaired (waiting for pickup)" or "completed." When an item is marked "completed" it is archived in the person's file, moved off of the "action required" list. 
Basically, I'd like to create something like this. What concepts do I need to know to make this, and more importantly, what do I need to know in the way of programming languages? I really only have some basic experience with Java, Python, and HTML/CSS, and never any networking. I realize it's a large undertaking, but I'd like to know what it would take for me to build this.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty standard task for a database. The only thing you'd need to do in whichever language you pick (if you don't just go for a straight database), is create an interface to talk to the database. You can find more than enough tutorials online, though unfortunately this question is too broad for [so].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please avoid asking open ended questions. This forum is for specific coding issues you run into.

Comment: Sorry @DaveA. For future reference, where should I go for these questions?

Comment: Alex, first try googling, buying who to over-view books, and finding tutorials. This is a common mistake so don't feel too bad ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely off-topic for this particular forum, but I will try to help:

The first thing you need to do is decide on the platform/framework you want to use. Nobody here will be able to tell you what the right choice is for you, so I would suggest that you evaluate the different options and go with the one that makes the most sense to you.

More than likely, you will end up choosing from the following:

1. ASP.NET (Web Forms, MVC)
2. Java (JSP, Servlet, Struts, etc.)
3. PHP (Symfony, Zend, Yii, Drupal, CodeIgniter, etc.)
4. Python (Django, Grok, etc.)
5. Ruby (Ruby on Rails, Merb, Sinatra, Hobo, etc.)

You will definitely need to become proficient with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript too. There is no way around them regardless of which platform you're on. If you are not familiar with these technologies I would learn them before trying to build the application. Knowing them will make everything easier, and will yield better overall usability and functionality.

That's just my two-cents, but I hope it helps. Good luck!